# Why does oracle move id's to caps?

Tags: oracle-10g

I had lowercase id and it didn't find it until I moved it to caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless explicitly stated, all identifiers in Oracle are in upper case. Also, anything within quotes is case sensitive. `'seq_test'` & `'SEQ_TEST'` don't ,mean the samething